# Nuitka Tree Shaking Import Syntax For Reduced Size

Tags: python, python-3.x, nuitka

If I'm trying to create a `.exe` from a python program using `nuitka`, is it important to specify imports explicitly to reduce output size, e.g.

```py
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainter, QFontMetrics
```

or will the following result in the same compiled executable size if I use generic imports?

```py
from PySide6 import QtGui
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @mkrieger1, it worked OK, I updated the question. its more geared towards size

Comment: And were the executable sizes the same with both alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; Doesn't seem to matter for package size, but could affect compile times

From creator of `nuitka` on gitter

> The first one is recommended, but it should be the same @parksj10
> One goal of Nuitka is to allow you to write the first style, and Nuitka ought to optimize it into the later.
> If you start to change your code to suite Nuitka, I have failed. :)

> ... but unreachable code is not yet well understood, it doesn't only pick `QtGui` and what it uses yet, but still everything that `PySide6` import loads, is also there, even if not accessible to your code.

> You will hear about "hard imports" somewhat when I compile time optimize things now. Maybe one day, `PySide6` will get hard imported too, but don't hold your breath. This will more like start with your own code first. Things like `PySide6` tend to do all sorts of init as as side effect, so `QtGui` will probably not work without much of it.